# How to add components to the frame?

Tags: java, swing

I am new to Swing programming. And I m trying to develop a desktop application. 
First all I need to create a login window, which should not be draggable and its position must be in center of the screen.

So by learning , I have created a window by the following code:

```
import com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Newframe {

    private JLabel label;

    JFrame frame;
    JButton btn;
    Newframe(){


        prepareGUI();

     }

     public static void main(String arg[]) {
          Newframe n=new Newframe();
          }


     public void prepareGUI(){
         frame=new JFrame();
         frame.setUndecorated(true);
         frame.setSize(300, 300);
         frame.setVisible(true);

         Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
         frame.setLocation(dim.width/2-frame.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-frame.getSize().height/2);

     }

    }
```

Now, I want to add components (e.g textfields, labels, buttons, etc...) to this created frame.
I m trying to add the components to the frame by initialize the components and add them to the frame ( by this **frame.add(jbutton)**) , but components are not going to add to the created frame...

Can any one help me for this?

Comment: You can also put your frame to the middle of the screen with `frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);` - It's easier.

Answer (score 3):

```
frame.getContentPane().add(component)
```

Note this may vary depending on the layout you use.

Also, it'd be better to put the UI in the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), with this:

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Newframe n=new Newframe();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. got understand... :)

Comment: @ArchanaSarang You should accept this answer if you found it most useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to add component to the frame and to center the frame you can use frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);.

```
public class Newframe {
private JLabel label;
private JTextField txt;
JFrame frame;
JButton btn;

Newframe() {
    prepareGUI();
}

public static void main(String arg[]) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Newframe n = new Newframe();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void prepareGUI() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    frame.setVisible(true);

    //  Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    // frame.setLocation(dim.width/2-frame.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-frame.getSize().height/2);
    label = new JLabel("Name");
    label.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 20);
    frame.add(label);
    txt = new JTextField();
    txt.setBounds(50, 10, 100, 20);
    frame.add(txt);
    btn = new JButton("OK");
    btn.setBounds(40, 40, 80, 20);
    frame.add(btn);
}
```

}

Comment: thanks Rafiq, But , by runnig your code, the button displayed in the whole frame